# Yii unique authentication, deny duplicates

Tags: php, session, yii, session-variables

I search easy way to deny duplicate session for user.
For example after login in website from my computer i should not be able to login from smartphone. 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could create a field in your table of users, and When the User login from a computer, update this field with the value of 1 for example, this would be the value of User logged in and When the user logout updating again this time with the value 0
and before making loguin questions Whether the field is 0 if otherwise They can not let in.

sorry with my english

Comment: It is also a solution, but I remember that in yii have such an opportunity, withouy dayabase change or more code writing but I can not find it. Thanks.